# Java, can regex's take variables?

Tags: java, regex, string, match

I was looking at REGEX's as a possible solution for a problem.  I made some sample Strings that contained words such as hello, hellllooo, hhhheello, etc. I then created a regex to find all of these types of words.  What I not what to do is look at sentence that may or may not contain an inputted word.  For example, you type in hellloo, I would like to scan my sentence for words similar to "hellloo" and return 'hello' if found in the sentence.  Can I create a regex that is sort of a variable of the user input?  If you type in hellloo then I would construct something that returns back similar words to your input from a sentence or file.

Two input strings

```
String line = "this is hello helloooo hellllooo hhhel hellll what can I do?";
String longLine = "hello man this what can up down where hey my there find now ok stuff jive super sam dude car";
```

my regex function

```
public static void regexChecker(String theRegex, String str2Check) {
        Pattern checkRegex = Pattern.compile(theRegex);
        Matcher regexMatcher = checkRegex.matcher(str2Check);

        while(regexMatcher.find()) {
            if(regexMatcher.group().length() != 0) {
                System.out.println(regexMatcher.group().trim());
            }
        }
    }
```

running this

```
regexChecker("\\s[h]*[e]*[l]*[l]*[o]*\\s", line);
```

returns

```
hello
hello
hellllooo
hellll
```

I would like to create a REGEX based off the user input 'helllooo' that returns hello from the second String longLine.  Not sure if regex is the right solution, but I would like to know if its possible.

Comment: Why did you put the letters in `[]`? Don't. --- Do you really want the letters to be optional, so it matches e.g. the word `ho`? Change `*` to `+` to require at least one of each letter. --- Replace both ``\\s`` with ``\\b`` to match word boundaries. --- Regex should be `"\\bh+e+l+l+o+\\b"`. See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sh0bmt/1) for demo.

Comment: Thanks, it should def be +

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your example captures what you want to do (repeated letters from the input word), you definitely can.

Conceptually, you want the following:

```
public String makeRegec(String input) {
    StringBuilder regex = new StringBuilder("\\b");
    if(input != null && input.length() > 0) {

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            regex.append(input.charAt(i)).append("+");
        }
    }
    regex.append("\\b*");//don't need this if you would accept hello, for example
    return regex.toString();
}
```

Of course, you could compile the pattern and return that instead

Answer (score 1):

try this

make regex function:

```
public static String makeRegex(String input) {
StringBuilder regex = new StringBuilder();
if(input != null && input.length() > 0) {

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        regex.append("[" + input.charAt(i) + "]{1,}");

    }
}
return regex.toString();
}
```

regex function:

```
public static ArrayList regexChecker(String theRegex, String str2Check) {
        Pattern checkRegex = Pattern.compile(theRegex);
        Matcher regexMatcher = checkRegex.matcher(str2Check);
       ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
       String findString = "";
        while(regexMatcher.find()) {
            if(regexMatcher.group().length() != 0) {
                findString = regexMatcher.group().trim();
                list.add(findString);

            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

used:

```
String line = "this is hello helloooo hellllooo hhhel hellll what can I do?";

    String input = "hello";

    ArrayList<String> list = regexChecker(makeRegex(input), line);

    for(int i = 0;i<list.size();i++)
        System.out.println(list.get(i));
```

returns:

```
hello
helloooo
hellllooo
```

Replace String:

```
System.out.println(line.replaceAll(makeRegex(input), input));
```

Comment: I can already get that output.  I'm trying to input Heeeellllooo and return Hello

Comment: use ReplaceAll:
System.out.println(line.replaceAll(makeRegex(input), input));

Comment: Why {1,} instead of + in your regex maker? Also, what about words like Hello where there are two 'l's? Would the first l in the regex eat all the ls?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String found = input.replaceAll(".*?((h)+(e)+(l)(l)+(o)+)?.*", "$2$3$4$5$6");
```

The result will either be "hello" or blank if there's nothing like hello in the input.